# regexp matching failure

Tags: java, regex

I have a long regular expression that matches this kind of pattern:
"AZ123/09JUL AAA PART1".

The regular expression follows (it has 8 matching groups):

```
String pattern =
    "\\A((?:(\\p{Alnum}{2}\\p{Alpha}??)(\\d{1,4})(\\p{Alpha})?)\\/(\\d{1,2}\\p{Alpha}{3})\\p{Blank}+(\\p{Alnum}{3})(\\p{Alnum}{3})?\\p{Blank}+PART(\\d{1,2}))\\s*$\r?\n?";
```

If I mistype my pattern,
then none of my matching groups are found and all values are null.
How do I make it safe,
if 1 group fails than others should remain.
For example,
this fails: "AZ123/09JUL PART1",
but I want to explicitly indicate which portion was not parsed.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/r21aa8/1

Comment: I think you can make each group optional with ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes I can see that it works if you delete text from end, but if you mistype in the middle all fails and that's my issue

Comment: It depends which items are grouped and which grouped items you want to make optional. This matches both your test samples `\A((?:(\p{alnum}{2}\p{alpha}??)(\d{1,4})(\p{alpha})?)/(\d{1,2}\p{alpha}{3})(?:\p{blank}+(\p{alnum}{3})(\p{alnum}{3})?)?\p{blank}+PART(\d{1,2}))\s*\z`

Comment: Example, this groups and makes them optional. The only thing required is a literal `/`  = `"\\A((?:(\\p{alnum}{2}\\p{alpha}??)(\\d{1,4})(\\p{alpha})?)?/(?:(\\d{1,2}\\p{alpha}{3}))?(?:\\p{blank}+(\\p{alnum}{3})(\\p{alnum}{3})?)?(?:\\p{blank}+PART(\\d{1,2}))?)\\s*\\z"` Even though optional, they are sequential. You can run into problems if you don't have enough _way point_ literals (or required sections) and have similar group expressions.

Comment: You could further partition the importance by making a larger group of sub-groups optional, but requiring a section of each group to be required. This is how you can deduce a general form, and at the same time, matching parts in their correct locations - this is paramount.

Comment: @marti6addams Provide some input strings that should be matched.